# PHP create new page for each id

Tags: php, html, forms, forum

I'm trying to create a forum in php.

I allow users to create topics, then when I click into a topic I want to open a new page, where we will discuss the subject. How do I create that new page for each `idTopic`?

I'm trying to do this on topics page (page2 is the new page):

```
<a href='page2.php?id=".$row['idMessage']."'></a>
```

But how do I do it? I need to create unlimited pages, but on each one there are things for each `idTopic`.

I have more code, but do I need `GET`'s?

**EDIT:**
It worked!! Thank you Jefferson Salvador.

Comment: How is created the new topic? is it stored in some way?

Comment: It's stored in database yes. I'm using XAMPP mySQL.

Comment: I already have that. I only need to create a page where i put mensages "inside" each Topic. When i click in a topic it shows up that new page, there i need to write things. Then on second topic it only shows the page, not the things i wrote. There i need to write new things

Comment: You want to create actual page for each id and get it stored and viewed? Most forums and blogs don't create actual files where individual thread or post exists. Instead, the idea of `slug` is used and also advantage of `mod_rewrite` of `.htaccess` is taken to make use of `slug`.

Comment: Yes! that's what i want. I already have that to create a topic, how do i store it in each topic and show in other page?

Comment: So, do you have `slug` stored in database for each discussion thread?

Comment: The only slug i have is the id, but i think the answer above might work. Seems good, but i still need help doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a default page that receives the topic for:

```
$_GET['idTopic'];
```

Then, you search the contents of that topic in the database.
The page is the same, what changes is the content that comes from the bank, understood?

### topics.php

```
<a href="forum.php?idTopic=<?= $row['idTopic']; ?> > <?= $row['topicName']; ?></a>
```

### forum.php

```
$sql = 'SELECT* FROM messages where idTopic = '.$_GET['topic'];
```

Comment: Yes! I kind of understood. I think that should work, but what code should i have? I only need the PHP code, not all.. but how it works? How i search the content of the topic in the databasa? How works that code?